# Play Can't pass parameter through url with scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I have this in my controller:

```
def greet(name: String) = Action {
    Ok("Hello " + name)
}
```

And this in my routes:

```
GET     /greet                      controllers.HomeController.greet(name)
```

I am getting an error saying:

**Bad Request**

For request 'GET /greet?asd' [Missing parameter: name]

How do I pass a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your `route` including the name parameter like this:

```
GET     /greet/:name       controllers.HomeController.greet(name)
```

or you can pass it as a `GET` Parameter like that:

Url: `www.example.com/greet?name=testing`

```
def greet(name: String) = Action {
 implicit request =>
   val maybeName: Option[String] = request.getQueryString("name")
   println(s'This is an optional parameter $maybeName')
   Ok('')
}
```